# How to render many large arrays in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm having some troubles to render my arrays inside components, because of their size.

I'll exemplify it with a medium array (not the worst neither best cenario).
I have the follow array:

```
 {"34764": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "38452": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "38453": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "38895": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "42680": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "44456": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "44457": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "44559": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "45802": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "46069": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "46080": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "46676": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "46677": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]}
```

So I have 13 cities, with 12 days for weather forecast each.
To show this data, I did 2 components. One big component to receive the cities (item group component), and another component to show each weather forecast (item component):

[image: groups schema]

I was trying to send the cities to the item group component through an for..of (best performance) but happens that it just return the first element.

So the only way that I was able to render all components was sending cities to the item group component through and flat list, and inside the item group component i did another flatlist to render  item components with the daily weather forecast.

But that way it renders to slow, and warns me with this:

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make
> sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React
> performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate,
> etc. {"contentLength": 3863.272705078125, "dt": 788, "prevDt": 14862}

And this is happening with a medium array (13 cities), I have cenarios with 40 ~ 50 cities (with 12 forecast days each).

What should I do to render it and improve performance?

Edit:
My render methods:
PS: I didnt finished anything yet, for now I'm just trying to render it smooth

page:

```
const [areas, setAreas] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getAreas() {
      const result = await IrrigationRepository.getAll();

      const groups = result.reduce((groups, item) => {
        const group = groups[item.psId] || [];
        group.push(item);
        groups[item.psId] = group;
        return groups;
      }, {});

      setAreas(groups);
    }

    getAreas();
  }, []);

  function renderForecast() {
    let areasGroup = Object.values(areas);

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={areasGroup}
        keyExtractor={item => item[0].id}
        renderItem={item => <ForecastGroup item={item} />}
      />
    );
  }
```

Item group component:

```
const ForecastGroup = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 22, color: 'black'}}>{item.item[0].psId}</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={item.item}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        horizontal={true}
        renderItem={({item}) => <ForecastItem item={item} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Item group component:

```
const ForecastItem = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Card style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>{item.date}</Text>
        <Card.Section
          content={[{text: item.value, text70: true, grey10: true}]}
          contentStyle={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            padding: 10,
          }}
        />
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: maybe you should also add render methods to the question.

Comment: I just did, thanks for the advice @omer.ersoy